# PySyde2 / fbs freeze / fail to execute script main

Tags: python, pycharm, pyside2, fbs

Hope you doing well guys! I am starting a project using PyCharm and also a Virtual Env. Can someone help please?
I have these file:

main.py with the code:

```
from fbs_runtime.application_context.PySide2 import ApplicationContext
import sys
from package.main_window import MainWindow
if __name__ == '__main__':
    appctxt = ApplicationContext()       # 1. Instantiate ApplicationContext
    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(250, 150)
    window.show()
    exit_code = appctxt.app.exec_()      # 2. Invoke appctxt.app.exec_()
    sys.exit(exit_code)
```

I have another file main_window.py with these code:
    from PySide2 import QtWidgets

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setup_ui()

    def setup_ui(self):
        self.create_widgets()
        self.modify_widgets()
        self.create_layouts()
        self.add_widgets_to_layouts()
        self.setup_connections()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.btn_click = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click")

    def modify_widgets(self):
        pass

    def create_layouts(self):
        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

    def add_widgets_to_layouts(self):
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.btn_click)

    def setup_connections(self):
        self.btn_click.clicked.connect(self.bouton_clicked)

    def bouton_clicked(self):
        message_box = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        message_box.setWindowTitle("Bravo")
        message_box.setText("Première application réussi")
        message_box.exec_()
```

Finally I have create a freeze.sh file with this:
    source ~/PycharmProjects/venv/Scripts/activate
    cd ~/PycharmProjects/echaufement/

```
fbs clean
fbs freeze
```

I cd my src/main folder and usig: sh freeze.sh 
it create a target folder containing my App.exe
but when open my App.exe I have the following error:  fail to execute script main
Finally after debugging -fbs freeze --debug- and I have this - see image please
Thank you for your help.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit @eyllanesc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there some pathing issue with `./Scripts/fbs-script.py` line 11?

Also as a general rule, `fbs` doesn't play well beyond python 3.6. Try freezing the app again when a python 3.6.x venv?

I've outlined how to use a python 3.6.x `virtualenv` to build `fbs` app here: [How to compile PyQt5 program that uses python 3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61206551/how-to-compile-pyqt5-program-that-uses-python-3-8/61534773#61534773)